# Is there a way to make Google Cloud Run pass on my Content-Type?

Tags: jakarta-mail, google-cloud-run

I'm running a java/jetty based application inside Docker/Google Cloud Run.

The response I'm sending has (among others) these headers

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; ...
Content-Length: 4849
Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)
```

but unfortunately the client receives - after Google proxies the request - something like this

```
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 5038
```

which breaks every client that expects a .. proper Content-Type and *entirely* breaks multi-part responses. Clients aren't under my control, so this is a potential showstopper that unfortunately only came up after actually building for and deploying to Cloud Run.

- Is there any chance to make this work/work around it?
- Is a significant/meaningful change of outgoing responses like this expected?

Not trusting myself to find a bug in a Google product I added a request/response log to jetty on the server now¹. The very last thing my server sees (looking at the outgoing response) is this:

```
2019-11-21 03:42:14,002 INFO [no.difi.oxalis.server.Main] Jetty response headers: 
AS2-From: PSG000186
AS2-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <1574307732619.1.1661451988.Oxalis@localhost>
AS2-To: PSG000186
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 03:42:10 GMT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha-1; 
    boundary="----=_Part_2_1332891644.1574307732643"
```

and sure enough, on the client side this Content-Type turns into "text/html".

As far as I can tell there is NO way for me to change anything at this point (and again: This same binary, the very same Docker image, does not behave that way when run locally with the very same input).

I wonder if the long Content-Type, the continuation part, breaks things here?

① Implementing [RequestLog](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.19.v20190610/org/eclipse/jetty/server/RequestLog.html) with a trivial

```
        @Override
        public void log(Request request, Response response) {
            String responseHeaders = response.getHeaderNames().stream().map(name -> { return name+": "+response.getHeader(name); }).collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"))
            + "\r\n\r\n";
            log.info("Jetty response headers: \r\n{}", responseHeaders);
        }
```

**Update**:

Minimal Test Case: Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce this in a tiny testcase (i.e. just spinning up an app that returns various Content-Types).

As for the exact traffic going in and out: This is a PEPPOL (think: business document exchange standard, mostly and in this case for .. invoices) endpoint. My sample files are slightly modified real invoices, so I'd need to find a way to reproduce this with completely anonymized data first.

**Update 2:**

Based on some official sample documents, these are the responses that the client receives (format as headers, blank line, full body):

Sending to `docker run -it --rm gcr.io/myproject/mytag` locally:

```
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 08:08:35 GMT
AS2-From: PSG000186
AS2-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <1574323717515.2.2091717429.Oxalis@fd713b389c13>
AS2-To: PSG000186
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha-1;           boundary="----=_Part_6_682736416.1574323717516"
Content-Length: 4856
Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)

------=_Part_6_682736416.1574323717516
Content-Type: multipart/report; Report-Type=disposition-notification;
        boundary="----=_Part_4_1507503463.1574323717515"

------=_Part_4_1507503463.1574323717515
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

= Received headers

Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 08:08:35 +0000
Message-Id: <1574323715268.1.-1501411008.Oxalis@fd713b389c13>
Subject: AS2 message from Oxalis
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha-1; boundary="----=_Part_1_1634611027.1574323715300"
AS2-From: PSG000186
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Oxalis 4.1.1-SNAPSHOT
Disposition-Notification-To: not.in.use@difi.no
AS2-Version: 1.0
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Disposition-Notification-Options: signed-receipt-protocol=required,pkcs7-signature; signed-receipt-micalg=required,sha1
AS2-To: PSG000186
Content-Length: 19479


------=_Part_4_1507503463.1574323717515
Content-Type: message/disposition-notification
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 08:08:36 +0000
Reporting-UA: Oxalis 4.1.1-SNAPSHOT
Original-Recipient: rfc822; PSG000186
Final-Recipient: rfc822; PSG000186
Original-Message-ID: <1574323715268.1.-1501411008.Oxalis@fd713b389c13>
X-Oxalis-Original-Content-Header: Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi94bWwNCkNvbnRlbnQtVHJhbnNmZXItRW5jb2Rpbmc6IGJhc2U2NA0KDQo=
Received-Content-Mic: yI4WRPi283i7xj5KOnRy3O+XCCU=, sha1
Disposition: automatic-action/MDN-sent-automatically; processed

------=_Part_4_1507503463.1574323717515--

------=_Part_6_682736416.1574323717516
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s; smime-type=signed-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature
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------=_Part_6_682736416.1574323717516--
```

Sending to Google Cloud service running the very same image:

```
as2-from: PSG000186
as2-version: 1.0
message-id: <1574323812231.2.1014381783.Oxalis@localhost>
as2-to: PSG000186
mime-version: 1.0
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 60c1258ef2c1295b01a27e3633acc267;o=1
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 08:10:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 5045
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000

------=_Part_6_1913495260.1574323812233
Content-Type: multipart/report; Report-Type=disposition-notification;
        boundary="----=_Part_4_1743408990.1574323812231"

------=_Part_4_1743408990.1574323812231
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

= Received headers

Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 08:10:10 +0000
message-id: <1574323810575.1.-368437367.Oxalis@fd713b389c13>
subject: AS2 message from Oxalis
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha-1; boundary="----=_Part_1_2065922950.1574323810605"
as2-version: 1.0
User-Agent: Oxalis 4.1.1-SNAPSHOT
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Host: einvoice-sg-inbound-7tyhycme6a-an.a.run.app
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
as2-from: PSG000186
x-cloud-trace-context: 60c1258ef2c1295b01a27e3633acc267/2200277044701127466;o=1
Forwarded: for="223.25.66.148";proto=https
X-Forwarded-For: 223.25.66.148
as2-to: PSG000186
disposition-notification-to: not.in.use@difi.no
disposition-notification-options: signed-receipt-protocol=required,pkcs7-signature; signed-receipt-micalg=required,sha1
Content-Length: 19479


------=_Part_4_1743408990.1574323812231
Content-Type: message/disposition-notification
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 08:10:11 +0000
Reporting-UA: Oxalis 4.1.1-SNAPSHOT
Original-Recipient: rfc822; PSG000186
Final-Recipient: rfc822; PSG000186
Original-Message-ID: <1574323810575.1.-368437367.Oxalis@fd713b389c13>
X-Oxalis-Original-Content-Header: Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi94bWwNCkNvbnRlbnQtVHJhbnNmZXItRW5jb2Rpbmc6IGJhc2U2NA0KDQo=
Received-Content-Mic: yI4WRPi283i7xj5KOnRy3O+XCCU=, sha1
Disposition: automatic-action/MDN-sent-automatically; processed

------=_Part_4_1743408990.1574323812231--

------=_Part_6_1913495260.1574323812233
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s; smime-type=signed-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature
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------=_Part_6_1913495260.1574323812233--
```

**Edit 3:**

I was asked in the comments to provide the body of the response - and did so above. But for all I care, for all I understand, this *should not matter*. If I see, server side, "Content-Type: foo/bar" after the request was handled, then that is what I expect to receive. If I dump the response first thing on the client, then it should show "Content-Type: foo/bar". Whether I send json, xml, multi-part, a binary or nothing at all. If my content is nonsense, formatted correctly or not: I expect a cloud service to relay my response to the service unchanged (ignoring necessary artifacts like additional X- headers etc).

**Edit 4:**

To make absolutely sure that there's nothing weird on the client going on or that it's somehow related to anything in the request itself, I created a curl script (taking out the java client library) POSTing a dumped request body (eliminating any potential differences in the body) with fixed headers from the same dumped request (eliminating even changes in headers like 'Date' and generated stuff like the multipart boundary).

I run the binary equivalent request with curl, once against my local docker image (Response Content-Type: multipart-signed; ..) and Cloud Run (Response Content-Type: text/html).

Differences between the responses:

- Local uses http, cloud http2
- Local responds with HTTP 100 Continue first
- Cloud mangles most of the headers to lowercase
- Cloud changes Content-Type to text/html (THE ISSUE)
- Cloud injects various infrastructure related headers, so response is slightly bigger

The actual **content** is the same (ignoring the mirrored/case-mangled headers). Content fine, headers messed up.

**Update 5:**

Added the javamail tag - maybe someone with more experience around that API can tell me if there's a way to avoid the header folding.

The code in question starts [here](https://github.com/difi/oxalis/blob/master/oxalis-extension/oxalis-as2/src/main/java/no/difi/oxalis/as2/util/SMimeMessageFactory.java#L104), the Content-Type header is set to

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha-1;       boundary="----=_Part_14_175240407.1574354551085"
```

after [MimeMessage.save() here](https://github.com/difi/oxalis/blob/master/oxalis-extension/oxalis-as2/src/main/java/no/difi/oxalis/as2/util/SMimeMessageFactory.java#L172). I have trouble following the code and understanding where the \t char comes from - and why. In my responses I have multiple multipart Content-Types and roughly half of them have a \t inside, half of them don't.

Comment: Hey @BenjaminPodszun , can you edit your question with more information, like: code snippet of where your are returning the mentioned response, logs, errors?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi The response is returned by a Jetty based open-source project I'm deploying. There are no errors (except on the client, saying "Erm, I really expected multi-part, not text/html")

Comment: Edit your question to show everything that the client is receiving including data. Create a test case that sends a small amount of data. What I find odd is that your multipart length is 4849. The GFE is returning a length of 5038. Multipart is larger than a data stream due to the insertion of the multipart headers. I would like to see the `text/html` data. Something else is going on here. As a side note, I have never seen this problem with many Cloud Run deployments (100+) and I have deliberately written code trying to break Cloud Run,

Comment: What data is your app returning? This looks like S/MIME Version 3. Include the headers for each part being sent.

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated the post for now - I wasn't able to reduce it to a simple "send 'ok' with content-type and see it break" sample so far. Sharing the exact data is problematic until I reduce this to something harmless - but may I ask why the content/body of the response should matter? Am I wrong to expect that I should receive what the server sends out (as verified by the response logger and correctly received when running the image locally)?

Comment: Nevermind - I grabbed some public sample files from online and added the full responses (header, body). The requests post the exact same content to the exact same docker image, running either locally or in Cloud Run.

Comment: Looking at these examples again side by side I have absolutely NO clue what is going on. I see a lot of headers being mangled, change their case to all lowercase (MIME-Version, AS2-To, Message-Id etc. etc.).
The difference in content length is probably because the headers received are part of the response - and Cloud Run sends extra headers. I'm okay with a change in Content-Length, I am not okay with Content-Type: text/html though.

Comment: I wanted to see the html (all output). If your data is secret, then don't post a question on Stackoverflow. Wait until you have data that can be included. It looks like you are sending S/MIME and those headers are being sent further down in the message. It looks like Cloud Run is either prepending additional data or translating data. I cannot tell as your question does not provide the information that I requested. Start by detailing what this application does and what type of data is being returned so that we are not guessing.

Comment: John, I'm not happy with the comment. For one, I believe I can post questions just fine. I also believe that the initial question contained what I see. But furthermore, after that I literally included the FULL response. You seem to misunderstand the question if you ask for html. There is no html. I don't send html. Google sets the Content-Type to text/html for a response that has nothing to do with html and that I included, headers and body as you requested, in the post above.

Comment: hey @BenjaminPodszun, Can you please explain to me the use case of your application? I'm working on your issue and trying to find an explanation for why Google Frontend is sending you "text/html". Also, you are saying it's an open source, can you link it please maybe I can reproduce the issue here.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi thanks a lot for looking into this. The software is open-source - https://github.com/difi/oxalis - but to run it you need a certificate which should be issued by a certain registry (and I believe the software enforces that - not entirely sure about that). I could help you set up a client. That only needs the pubkey that I can provide. Are you able to bypass whatever sits in front of the service? Can you run a client like me and then 'internally' to see if there's a difference already?

Comment: I'm looking actively into this issue. however, it seems deep and maybe I would suggest you to contact [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/role-based-support) so they can look into this as they have the tools to troubleshoot what's happening here.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi I'll try and see how I can do that. This project runs with my own private billing information (and still in a trial period), with no organization resource attached - the problem literally came up in a proof of concept stage. My employer might have access to an account that can actually contact support, will try and find out during SEA daytime. As for now, that road is closed to me :-/

Comment: @JohnHanley I appreciate your time and any help with the issue. Blame it on me for a) being frustrated with this issue and b) potentially a language barrier (not my native language). Tbf, I really hope that the content of the response should not be relevant - but I did include it for both local and cloud run environments in response to your first request (see Update 2). Just took me some time to generate a sample from genuinely harmless data. At this point I don't quite know what to do. It's ~2am, so tomorrow I'll see what happens if I just have a container with nc spitting out the response?

Comment: We are investigating internally.

Comment: @wlhee Appreciated (and it seems Adrian can reproduce it). Now I wonder whether this is something that GCR wants to handle in the future or not. I understand that header folding is deprecated by now, but the code in use here (Java MimeMessage stuff) probably is too old to care. Should this work? Would you expect it to start working at some point?

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to reproduce the behavior of replacing the Content-Type with text/html if the Content-Type is set to any string that contains certain ASCII control characters between 0x01 and 0x19, including the tab character 0x09.  Does the Content-Type you are setting contain a tab before the word "boundary"? If so, see if you can replace that tab with a space.

Comment: I don't generate the header myself, but let me try and modify that in my request filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I looked into it some more today. If I'm not completely wrong, the header is created by some (probably ancient) javax.mail code when building a MimeMessage. While I can try and build a response filter for jetty - I'm looking at documentation right now - that's not a good solution moving forward: I now need to fork the project for this.
Could you clarify whether you'd call this a bug in GCR to give me an idea of whether this is going to go away in the ~near~ future?

Comment: It appears from [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2) that both space (0x20) and tab (0x09) should be permitted as whitespace characters in header values, so we are treating modification of such headers as a bug.

Comment: Is there any changelog / any feed I can subscribe to for this? To get notified when it will be fixed? Is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144880273 a good way to track it (do you guys use that to triage/update bugs or is everything internal only)?