# Local container responds with correct image content-type, but once hosted on gcloud, the same container returns an html content-type

Tags: docker, gcloud

I have a Docker container, that hosts an express site. All it does, is run sharp - and resizes an image.

This works totally fine. I run this container locally, and it does exactly what I want it to.

But then, when I deploy this image to gcloud (Google Run) using `gcloud run build`, and `gcloud run deploy`, the container deploys fine and I can access it, but now the exact same URL that I ran locally (except for swapping out the domain), it returns the image garbled as content-type html. This is from DevTools looking at the Network Tab at the response headers.

```
content-length: 4990
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 06:11:44 GMT
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
x-powered-by: Express
```

And this is the response I see when I run the container locally.

```
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 06:20:21 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: Express
```

I don't understand how I could get a different response (not withstanding any additional artefact headers Google might add) - when it is the same container I am running? Especially because gcloud results in text/html, and when I use the local container I see the resized image in my browser.

Any ideas where I might look? As I said - it works flawlessly if I run the container locally using Docker.

The test URL is:

https://image-processor-74rmztaj4a-uc.a.run.app/test

For what it's worth, the relevant express route is, but as I said - there is no real problem with the actual code ... It's more with the deployment to Google Cloud Run...

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  const transform = sharp()
    .resize(200, 200, { fit: "inside" })
    .toFormat("jpeg");

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./src/image.jpg");

  return readStream.pipe(transform).pipe(res);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: The only difference I can see is that locally the traffic is http, and on gcloud it is https ... But I can't see how that would make a difference.

Comment: Hello, it looks like this could be related with this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951943/is-there-a-way-to-make-google-cloud-run-pass-on-my-content-type), what do you think, have to checked the answers there?

Comment: Hi Luis - yes - this is a very similar case it seems, where the Google Frontend Server randomly assigns "text/html" to the content-type header, even though the stream I am putting into the response is an image. It works locally when I run the container - but differently once deployed to gcloud.

Comment: I've simplified the express route down to it's essence in the question, and added the response headers when I look at the requests in my Chrome Devtools

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type explicitly, in a way to enforce the content type? I suggest this as, maybe, for some reason, if Cloud run is changing the content type, it could be as there is no content type set in the response.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you - if I set it explicitly, it works. So it must be that when headers aren't set explicitly, Google Frontend Server reverts to "text/html". So it works locally because there is no Google Frontend Server inbetween, and the content-type is simply inferred.

Comment: Sure, I will post this as an answer just so that the post has a resolution : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the content-type was being modified by Cloud run, but the solution on this situations is just to specify the content-type for the response to make it work as expected.